# on submit form remove part of the word of input value

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a form that submits fields. I'm using Google autocomplete to suggest location and populate fields. Problem is that it adds extra words to the locations like `-si`, `-do`, etc.
I need to remove these extra words on submit.
I have this JQuery code but it does not work:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("form").submit(function () {
         $('input[name=locality').val.replace('-si', '');
         //return value.replace('-si', '');
     });
 });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $('input[name=locality').val().replace('-si', ''); you missed brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("form").submit(function () {
         var inp = $('input[name=locality]');
         inp.val(inp.val().replace('-si', ''));
     });
 });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjSjw/)

Comment: That was it. Now I have 3 fields like this I was planning to make function for each field but I'll still ask. Is there a way to make an array of words to be replaced and add all 3 fields to be affected? If not I'll just make it for each field separate. Thanks.

Comment: you can add to inputs css class, and use like this: $('.myInput').each(function(){this.val(this.val().replace('-si', ''))})

Comment: Ok I see. I have few words to be looked for and removed (-si, -do, -dong) can I put those in array somehow? so if any of the fields have any of those 3 words in the value, it will remove them.

Comment: Maybe like this: var replacewords = (-si, -do, -dong) $('.myInput').each(function(){this.val(this.val().replace('replacewords', ''))})

Comment: use RegExp like this: $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/-si|-do|-dong/g, ''));